# Visual Studio Code Директива #include

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Мне нужно сделать проект под линукс на плюсах, не когда ранее не  программировал под него. Сейчас вот поставил Visual Studio Code на Ubuntu установил все зависимости, clang, и врочие... Добавил все расширения под С++ что нашел в списке расширений... Вобщем вроде все настроил.

Столкнулся с ошибкой которая много раз уже обсуждалась, однако я не смог ее победить пока. Простейший Hello World - не могу собрать из за проблем с зависимостями.

Ниже мой код:

```
#include <oisteam>

int main()
{
    std::cout <<"HW";
    return 0;
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/usr/include/c++",
                "/usr/include/c++/7",
                "/usr/include/c++/7.3.0",
                "${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "/usr/include",
                    "/usr/local/include",
                    "/usr/include/c++",
                    "/usr/include/c++/7",
                    "/usr/include/c++/7.3.0",
                    "${workspaceFolder}" 
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Все время одна и та же ошибка: 
cannot open source file "oistem"

Буду благодарен за помощь...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы заменил

```
#include <oisteam>
```

на

```
#include <iostream>
```

и попробовал еще раз...

Comment: Блин, как же глупо то вышло))  спасибо большое, я из за этой опечатки уже час убил))) нужно внимательнее быть !

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar Это нормально. Когда нет проверки синтаксиса на валидность по часу ищешь ошибки в операторах типа `else` и `esle`. Старайтесь, до написания темы пару раз, хотя бы, перечитать свой код.

Comment: -1 от меня. Такие вещи пишут в комментариях, а вопросы закрывают. Отвечая на подобные вопросы, Вы усложняете их удаление.

Comment: Да, в VS2017 сразу бы сыпало отборным... :))) Я как-то пробовал разные конфигурации для С++ в Ubuntu, но в итоге установил две ОС и установил Visual Studio, проблемы ушли...